# 415 unsupported media type With Angular JS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

**Spring code**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers = "content-type=application/json;application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody String addNewCinemaCampaign( @RequestBody @Valid User user)
{
    System.out.println(user!=null?user.getName():"Null");
    return userService.createUser(user);
}
```

I am creating new user via Angular post method but I am getting always 415 unsupported media type.
Please resolve this problem...

Comment: can you post your AngularJS code that is responsible for calling your rest service??

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be helpful in your case:

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

So in your code it will be

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String addNewCinemaCampaign( @RequestBody @Valid User user)
{
    System.out.println(user!=null?user.getName():"Null");
    return userService.createUser(user);
}
```